# Postgresql /copy for inserting enum value

Tags: postgresql, enums, postgresql-9.5

Let's say I have an enum: `CREATE TYPE foo AS ENUM ('a', 'b', 'c')`
And a column in my table of type `foo`.

Assuming I want to insert a .tsv file that has, as the value respective to the enum column the string `"a"` or `"b"` or `"c"`, what is the most efficient way to go about doing that ?

I have ~90 million rows here, so inserting them one by one could be considerably slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres provides the [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) command for importing data from a file. If the strings in the file are exactly written as the enum members, this should work out of the box.

```
COPY elbat
     (nmuloc_1,
      ...,
      nmuloc_n)
     FROM '/path/to/file.tsv';
```

Comment: CORRECT! If you end up with problems here (like I was) it might be due to some other error, e.g problems with encoding/escaping/quoting complicated data like JSON fields.